# How to make a bundle for android about react native app

Tags: react-native

I know I can run 'react-native bundle' command to make a bundle for android, but I don't know how to let my app use resource not from dev server but from the bundle. I need write the path about bundle in iOS. And what should I do for android.THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate your bundles as described before, then:

*For android: (in MainApplication.java)*

```
public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
  return false;
  //return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
}
```

*For iOS: (in AppDelegate.m)*

```
//debugserver with fallback bundle
//  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
//always bundle
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

I think both also change automatically when you build a realease in production mode... but I've been using this to be sure it always uses the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentations, you can run:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/com/your-company-name/app-package-name/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/com/your-company-name/app-package-name/src/main/res/
```

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/docs/IntegrationWithExistingApps.md#creating-a-release-build-in-android-studio

Comment: I know how to make a bundle for android, but I want to know how to make my android app get resource from bundle. THX